# Will this motherboard's front port headers work with the front ports on this case?

Tags: motherboard, case

- **Motherboard**: [TUF GAMING X570-PRO WIFI II](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards-Components/Motherboards/TUF-Gaming/TUF-GAMING-X570-PRO-WIFI-II/)
- **Case**: [Corsair iCUE 5000X RGB Tempered Glass Mid-Tower ATX PC Smart Case, Black, CC-9011212-WW](https://www.newegg.com/black-corsair-icue-5000x-rgb-atx-mid-tower/p/N82E16811139163)

I'm so confused on what to do about a case, because I'm dead set on using this motherboard, and the USB versions confuse the heck out of me, and I can't find adapters for that motherboard for that case, so are they already compatible?

I also want to use this case, because my build's style depends on using this exact case.

The case only has 3.0 ports and a USB 3.1 Type-C, and the motherboard has a USB 3.2 Gen 2 header (Type C) and a USB 3.2 Gen 1 header.

I just need a simple yes or no, and maybe a brief explanation.

Comment: You're more likely to get an answer at https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @DrMoishePippik  I think  he will almost certainly be able to get an answer here ..lots of pc builders here, and he's not asking for a hardware recommendation. And many people here are familiar with USB mumbo jumbo

Comment: I haven't kept that up to date re USB things or built a comp for a long while, no doubt some here will be able to answer  but this link may be  helpful. https://pcguide101.com/motherboard/what-are-usb-headers/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is better suited for the [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com) SE site.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 why not flag it for moving rather than voting to close it?

Comment: @barlop Is there an option to move to Hardware Recs in that area? I don’t recall.  A mod sees this anyway and will act accoringly.

Comment: There isn't a move path for hardwarerecs.

Comment: USB 3.0 is equivalent to (USB 3.1 Gen 1 and USB 3.2 Gen 2)

Comment: AT Ramhound You wrote "USB 3.0 is equivalent to (USB 3.1 Gen 1 and USB 3.2 Gen 2)" <-- I don't know much about these names, but what you wrote looks wrong, see the table here https://www.tomshardware.com/news/usb-3.0-usb-3.1-becomes-usb-3.2,38699.html   So, 3.0 got a new name in terms of 3.1, as 3.1 Gen 1. Then got a new name in terms of 3.2 as 3.2 Gen 1.     Never as USB 3.2 Gen 2.  If you want to know what USB 3.2 Gen 2 was, then look at the table, it's not USB 3.0, it's USB 3.1

Comment: @barlop The point is motherboard's header connectors are the same.

Comment: @ChanganAuto  If we take Ramhound's statement "USB 3.0 is equivalent to (USB 3.1 Gen 1 and USB 3.2 Gen 2)"  And let's suppose he means Just the motherboard headers. Then that still looks maybe wrong. The pcguide link says there are  thus far 4 types of USB header.  "USB 2.0 Header, USB 3.0 Header, USB 3.1 Gen 2 Header, USB 3.2 Gen 2×2 Header.  "   Now see the toms link. USB 3.0 header is Gen 1 . So Gen 1 and Gen 2 have different USB headers., So a)looks like the different USB speeds do have different USB headers.  b)the ones ramhound mentions have different USB headers . I'm no expert though

Comment: @barlop Yes, headers are different in the sense that they provide slightly different features but all USB 3.x header connectors are the same. So, the question being "can I use the this case's front ports with this motherboard?" we can say yes regardless of USB3.x generation.

Comment: @ChanganAuto well if all one is looking for is compatibility, then even if they weren't compatible, there are apparently adaptors as mentioned  here https://www.reddit.com/r/buildapc/comments/eq57v8/are_motherboard_usb_headers_backwards_compatible/ But  also, I suppose that typically one wouldn't really want to use  a case with slower USB ports than a motherboard provides, imo , and perhaps for many, it'd be preferable to mod the case(even if done in an ugly way), and attach faster USB ports. Or to use a different case. In his situation  I see he has special requirement to use the case

Comment: @barlop The ports, cables and connectors are just that, wires and terminations. Newer USB3 generations didn't add any new connectors, unlike what happened from USB2 to USB3. It's a moot point. The Reddit you linked is about an old case with USB2.0 only and no, there aren't adapters for that situation but in the end the OP found out the board actually have USB2.0 headers so the case's USB2.0 front panel can be used as is. The case in this question has USB3.x frontal panel and it can be used regardless of the "x".